# Jest mock @electron/remote module

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, electron, ts-jest

I have some problems with my tests since I upgraded from electron v11 to v20.
With this update the `remote` was moved from electron to a new module `@electron/remote`.

In `jest.config.js` I have the electron module mock mapping: `electron: '<rootDir>/tests/mock/electron.mock.ts'`

```
...
const mockIpcRenderer = {
  on: jest.fn(),
  send: jest.fn()
};
const mockRemote = {
  app: {
    getPath: mockGetPath,
    getAppPath() {
      return '/app/working/path';
    }
  },
  process: {
    env: jest.fn()
  }
};
...
export const ipcRenderer = mockIpcRenderer;
export const remote = mockRemote;
```

So, after the update I extracted the `remote` part from the mock to a new file: `remote.mock.ts`

```
const mockApp = {
  getPath: mockGetPath,
  getAppPath() {
    return '/app/working/path';
  }
};

const mockProcess = {
  env: jest.fn()
};

function mockGetPath(path: string) {
  return 'somtething';
}

export const app = mockApp;
export const process = mockProcess;
```

and I added this line to my test file:

`jest.mock('@electron/remote', () => require('../mock/remote.mock'));`

The problem is when I run the test I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`.
The `ipcRenderer` is undefined and I don't know why ?
When I added that `jest.mock('@electron/remote', () => require('../mock/remote.mock'));` to the test file, the mocks from `electron.mock.ts` are not defined anymore, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the `jest.config.js` I added *start* and *end* symbols and added a new line for `@electron/remote` and it works.

```json
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^@electron/remote$': '<rootDir>/tests/mock/electron.mock.ts',
  '^electron$': '<rootDir>/tests/mock/electron.mock.ts',
},
```